# libgdx connection error can't setup third party libs through the ui

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

The first three times I used my gdx-setup-ui it worked fine and I was able to add something like Tween Engine to my projects. Now for some reason every time I load up the setup, it instantly says v3.0.0 connection error as well as the Master config file and Version number red notifications at the bottom. With no connection it won't allow me to setup or even see third party libraries.

I have no other error log no idea why there is a connection error, it was working before and not its not(no restart in between). What could possibly be the problem and resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why you're getting this error as I'm also receiving this error.

This is the message from the libGDX site:

The old setup UI has been deprecated, the audio and image extensions have been removed, and the demos have been gradelized and put into their own repositories. You can now also directly test the demos in your browser (or desktop, or Android device)!

It seems that libgdx is officially in version 1.0 and no longer storing previous updates or config files in their repository. Now you need to update to version 1.0 and follow the instructions on how to setup here:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3336

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOXLAlP9lww#t=100